# Vuejs component method generate html that have onclick and will call another method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components, vue-component

Is there any solution when generating html on method, and the html tag have onclick event listener to other vuejs method?

```
Methods :{
    methodOne(){
         //...
         return '<button class="del-btn" onclick="methodTwo(this,event)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'
    },
    methodTwo(elm,event){
       //... 
    }
}
```

I have tried to use `@click="methodTwo(this,event)"` and `@click="this.methodTwo(this,event)" but still not working..

Comment: This isn't how Vue works. It would require dynamic compilation, which is a corner case. You likely have XY problem. Consider explaining your case instead of focusing on potentially wrong way to solve it